# Speeding up build process with distutils

Tags: c++, python, distutils

I am programming a C++ extension for Python and I am using distutils to compile the project. As the project grows, rebuilding it takes longer and longer. Is there a way to speed up the build process?

I read that parallel builds (as with `make -j`) are not possible with distutils. Are there any good alternatives to distutils which might be faster?

I also noticed that it's recompiling all object files every time I call `python setup.py build`, even when I only changed one source file. Should this be the case or might I be doing something wrong here?

In case it helps, here are some of the files which I try to compile: https://gist.github.com/2923577

Thanks!

Comment: How is your build process? Do you always clean/rebuild? How is your code (specially headers)? Are you using forward declarations? What is your environment? Can you use precompiled headers?

Comment: I didn't know how to answer all of your questions, so I added a link to part of the source code. I am building the project with `python setup.py build`, is there a better way or better command? The environments are linux and Mac.

Comment: Recompiling all object files is expected: Extension extra options may change the output without changing the .c file.  http://bugs.python.org/issue5372

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. Try building with environment variable `CC="ccache gcc"`, that will speed up build significantly when the source has not changed. (strangely, distutils uses `CC` also for c++ source files). Install the ccache package, of course.
2. Since you have a **single extension** which is assembled from **multiple compiled object files**, you can monkey-patch distutils to compile those in parallel (they are independent) - put this into your setup.py (adjust the `N=2` as you wish):

   ```
   # monkey-patch for parallel compilation
   def parallelCCompile(self, sources, output_dir=None, macros=None, include_dirs=None, debug=0, extra_preargs=None, extra_postargs=None, depends=None):
       # those lines are copied from distutils.ccompiler.CCompiler directly
       macros, objects, extra_postargs, pp_opts, build = self._setup_compile(output_dir, macros, include_dirs, sources, depends, extra_postargs)
       cc_args = self._get_cc_args(pp_opts, debug, extra_preargs)
       # parallel code
       N=2 # number of parallel compilations
       import multiprocessing.pool
       def _single_compile(obj):
           try: src, ext = build[obj]
           except KeyError: return
           self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
       # convert to list, imap is evaluated on-demand
       list(multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(N).imap(_single_compile,objects))
       return objects
   import distutils.ccompiler
   distutils.ccompiler.CCompiler.compile=parallelCCompile
   ```
3. For the sake of completeness, if you have **multiple extensions**, you can use the following solution:

   ```
   import os
   import multiprocessing
   try:
       from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Pool
   except ImportError:
       from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as LegacyPool

       # To ensure the with statement works. Required for some older 2.7.x releases
       class Pool(LegacyPool):
           def __enter__(self):
               return self

           def __exit__(self, *args):
               self.close()
               self.join()

   def build_extensions(self):
       """Function to monkey-patch
       distutils.command.build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions

       """
       self.check_extensions_list(self.extensions)

       try:
           num_jobs = os.cpu_count()
       except AttributeError:
           num_jobs = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

       with Pool(num_jobs) as pool:
           pool.map(self.build_extension, self.extensions)

   def compile(
       self, sources, output_dir=None, macros=None, include_dirs=None,
       debug=0, extra_preargs=None, extra_postargs=None, depends=None,
   ):
       """Function to monkey-patch distutils.ccompiler.CCompiler"""
       macros, objects, extra_postargs, pp_opts, build = self._setup_compile(
           output_dir, macros, include_dirs, sources, depends, extra_postargs
       )
       cc_args = self._get_cc_args(pp_opts, debug, extra_preargs)

       for obj in objects:
           try:
               src, ext = build[obj]
           except KeyError:
               continue
           self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)

       # Return *all* object filenames, not just the ones we just built.
       return objects


   from distutils.ccompiler import CCompiler
   from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
   build_ext.build_extensions = build_extensions
   CCompiler.compile = compile
   ```

Comment: Great monkey-patch! +1. To help when debugging, I also added a try block around the `imap()` iteration, to catch `CompileError`'s, only raising them after terminating / joining the `ThreadPool`. That way I can still easily see the exact compile command that failed at the bottom of the output, whilst not orphaning any processes.

Comment: Has anybody been successful with the monkey-patch on windows? I have tried it but it looks like it skips building the objects and jumps straight to the link step!

Comment: @Nick: I use it also under Windows and it works. You could get some diagnostics by putting a print statement before `self._compile` to see what is actually about to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This works best for a single extension, with multiple objects. In my case I had several extensions with one objects each. I ended up relying on the new `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` instead, and a single global `pool` outside of the function definition.

Comment: @jadelord could you possibly point to an example of that? I'd like to see how you accelerated compilation with multiple extension.

Comment: @Vyas, I have edited the answer above with a minimal example. While the edit is being approved, you can also find it [being applied here](https://bitbucket.org/fluiddyn/fluidsim/src/95fe0c78db758931f0371bdfe16647c4cc087510/config.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#config.py-133:214)

Comment: Great thanks! Out of curiosity, is there a reason you prefer this over just doing python setup.py build_ext -j NTHREAD && python setup.py install?

Comment: @Vyas I never heard of setup.py supporting -j NTHREAD. Besides, this one can build one extension from many files in parallel.

Comment: Right, the original answer provided here parallelized over one extension to build many files at once, and you added the ability to parallelize over multiple extensions. I had just been using the original version of this answer (for parallelizing within one extension) and then using setup.py -j (for parallelizing across multiple extensions), so I was curious how and why you implemented yours. However, I have found that setuptools doesn't appear to support -j for Python2.7, so perhaps that was added after you originally wrote your version. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Yes, that was long time ago while still stuck with 2.7. Good to hear setup.py now supports -j :)

Comment: I don't think normal setup.py supports -j N, at least it didn't for a single extension. However, Numpy does since version 1.10, and you can hack it in with `from numpy.distutils.ccompiler import CCompiler_compile; import distutils.ccompiler; distutils.ccompiler.CCompiler.compile = CCompiler_compile`, ideally surrounded by try except for ImportError on numpy.

Answer (score 9):

I've got this working on Windows with clcache, derived from eudoxos's answer:

```
# Python modules
import datetime
import distutils
import distutils.ccompiler
import distutils.sysconfig
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.pool
import os
import sys

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.core import Extension
from distutils.errors import CompileError
from distutils.errors import DistutilsExecError

now = datetime.datetime.now

ON_LINUX = "linux" in sys.platform

N_JOBS = 4

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Enable ccache to speed up builds

if ON_LINUX:
    os.environ['CC'] = 'ccache gcc'

# Windows
else:

    # Using clcache.exe, see: https://github.com/frerich/clcache

    # Insert path to clcache.exe into the path.

    prefix = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(prefix, "bin")

    print "Adding %s to the system path." % path
    os.environ['PATH'] = '%s;%s' % (path, os.environ['PATH'])

    clcache_exe = os.path.join(path, "clcache.exe")

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Parallel Compile
#
# Reference:
#
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013851/speeding-up-build-process-with-distutils
#

def linux_parallel_cpp_compile(
        self,
        sources,
        output_dir=None,
        macros=None,
        include_dirs=None,
        debug=0,
        extra_preargs=None,
        extra_postargs=None,
        depends=None):

    # Copied from distutils.ccompiler.CCompiler

    macros, objects, extra_postargs, pp_opts, build = self._setup_compile(
        output_dir, macros, include_dirs, sources, depends, extra_postargs)

    cc_args = self._get_cc_args(pp_opts, debug, extra_preargs)

    def _single_compile(obj):

        try:
            src, ext = build[obj]
        except KeyError:
            return

        self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)

    # convert to list, imap is evaluated on-demand

    list(multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(N_JOBS).imap(
        _single_compile, objects))

    return objects


def windows_parallel_cpp_compile(
        self,
        sources,
        output_dir=None,
        macros=None,
        include_dirs=None,
        debug=0,
        extra_preargs=None,
        extra_postargs=None,
        depends=None):

    # Copied from distutils.msvc9compiler.MSVCCompiler

    if not self.initialized:
        self.initialize()

    macros, objects, extra_postargs, pp_opts, build = self._setup_compile(
        output_dir, macros, include_dirs, sources, depends, extra_postargs)

    compile_opts = extra_preargs or []
    compile_opts.append('/c')

    if debug:
        compile_opts.extend(self.compile_options_debug)
    else:
        compile_opts.extend(self.compile_options)

    def _single_compile(obj):

        try:
            src, ext = build[obj]
        except KeyError:
            return

        input_opt = "/Tp" + src
        output_opt = "/Fo" + obj
        try:
            self.spawn(
                [clcache_exe]
                + compile_opts
                + pp_opts
                + [input_opt, output_opt]
                + extra_postargs)

        except DistutilsExecError, msg:
            raise CompileError(msg)

    # convert to list, imap is evaluated on-demand

    list(multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(N_JOBS).imap(
        _single_compile, objects))

    return objects

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Only enable parallel compile on 2.7 Python

if sys.version_info[1] == 7:

    if ON_LINUX:
        distutils.ccompiler.CCompiler.compile = linux_parallel_cpp_compile

    else:
        import distutils.msvccompiler
        import distutils.msvc9compiler

        distutils.msvccompiler.MSVCCompiler.compile = windows_parallel_cpp_compile
        distutils.msvc9compiler.MSVCCompiler.compile = windows_parallel_cpp_compile

# ... call setup() as usual
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this easily if you have Numpy 1.10 available. Just add:

```py
 try:
     from numpy.distutils.ccompiler import CCompiler_compile
     import distutils.ccompiler
     distutils.ccompiler.CCompiler.compile = CCompiler_compile
 except ImportError:
     print("Numpy not found, parallel compile not available")
```

Use `-j N` or set `NPY_NUM_BUILD_JOBS`.

Answer (score 1):

In the limited examples you provided in the link, it seems fairly obvious that you have some misunderstanding on what some of the features of the language are. For example, the `gsminterface.h` has a whole lot of namespace level `static`s, which is probably unintended. Every translation unit that includes that header will compile it's own version for everyone of the symbols declared in that header. Side effects of this are not only the compile time but also code bloat (larger binaries) and link time as the linker needs to process all those symbols.

There are still many questions that affect the build process that you have not answered, for example, whether you clean every time before you recompile. If you are doing that, then you might want to consider `ccache`, which is a tool that *caches* the result of the build process, so that if you run `make clean; make target` only the preprocessor will be run for any translation unit that has not changed. Note that as long as you keep maintaining most code in headers, this will not offer much of an advantage, as a change in a header modifies all translation units that include it. (I don't know your build system, so I cannot tell you whether `python setup.py build` will *clean* or not)

The project does not seem large otherwise, so I would be surprised if it took more than a few seconds to compile.

Comment: I followed the tutorial and API documentation at http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html, which also uses `static` a lot. I don't explicitly clean the build (i.e., I don't call `python setup.py clean`) and it doesn't seem as if simply invoking `python setup.py build` performs a clean before rebuilding, although I am not sure *what* it does. And you're right, the build only takes about 40s. But if it would only take 10s, I would be happier.

Comment: @Lucas: The tutorial might be referring to functions defined in a single translation unit, not a header. Namespace level `static` symbols in a header make no sense. Just declare the function (without `static`) and define them in a single translation unit (again, no `static`). That will reduce the number of translation units to recompile when you only change implementations, and the cost of recompiling when the header also changes.

Comment: @dribeas: Thanks, I [reorganized the code](https://github.com/lucastheis/cisa/tree/0218a8fe7f46c70e43ca41158164585accfe9a71/code/isa) and although it didn't speed up the build process (all translation units still always get recompiled), I think the code makes much more sense now.