# How can I parallelize the compilation of Python packages?

Tags: python, compilation, pip

Some Python packages (e.g., numpy, scipy) have to compile a large number of source files when you install the package. Is there a way to parallelize the compile step? If I were building the source code myself, I might do something like "make -j4" to take advantage of 4 CPUs. Is there some equivalent when installing Python packages?

Answer (score 0):

How are you installing these packages?

Have you already reviewed this: [Speeding up build process with distutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013851/speeding-up-build-process-with-distutils/13176803#13176803)

Comment: I'm just installing using pip. The distutils monkey patch is interesting.